# Replace NA with text for specific ids

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the code and data below how can I replace `NAs` in column `a` with `Transportation Element Maps 2012` based on specific `ids` in column `id`?

Code:

```
# Sample df
df = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), a = c("a", "Transportation Element Maps 2012", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

# Desired df
df1 = structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), a = c("a", "Transportation Element Maps 2012", "Transportation Element Maps 2012", "Transportation Element Maps 2012", "Transportation Element Maps 2012", "Transportation Element Maps 2012", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

# Current approach which throws an error
df1 = df %>% ifelse(id %in% 3:6) %>%  mutate(a %in% NA, "Transportation Element Maps 2012")

# Error
Error in ifelse(., reference_number %in% 3:6) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

Comment: When you write `df %>% ifelse(id %in% 3:6)`, you are doing ifelse(df, id %in% 3:6)`. R is trying to evaluate whether `df` is `TRUE`, which is why you are seeing the error `'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'`.

Comment: Thank you, as I always like to know the reason behind an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is.na` to find NA elements that returns a logical vector, as well as keep the `id %in% 3:6` within `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(a = ifelse(id %in% 3:6 & is.na(a), 
      "Transportation Element Maps 2012", a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `replace` function and combine `3:6` and `NA` together using `c` as follow:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(a = replace(a, id %in% c(3:6, NA), "Transportation Element Maps 2012"))
```

Comment: Cool, thank you, btw is `|>` the new pipping symbol for `%>%`?